# Avoiding game loop in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, game-loop

I developing a simple 3D model viewer on XNA 4.0. Is there a way to avoid a infinite game loop with Draw and Update functions? I need render 3D graphics, but without infinite rendering of scene. I mean I need redraw the scene only then it really changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at how they're doing it in their samples:

[App Hub - WinForms Series 1](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)
[App Hub - WinForms Series 2](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2)

Answer (score 2):

Why exactly do you want this?

If you use a winforms application you have more control on your update and draw loop, but you also could render the scene to a texture first, and then stop rendering at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to roll your own multi-threaded loop; if you stall either `Update` or `Draw` the other will get stalled too. Another consideration is that if your window gets obscured somehow (under non-DWM environments; a window overlapping it for instance) stalling the `Draw` will leave areas of your window unpainted.

If you want to go ahead with this; what you will do is start a `Thread` the first time `Update` gets called and subsequently use a `ManualResetEvent` to synchronise the two.

A far more robust option is to render your entire scene to a `RenderTarget2D` when the scene is updated; if the scene has not been altered since the last `Update` or `Draw` call simply render the `RenderTarget2D` instead of the whole scene. This is still an infinite loop, but it tends toward your requirement (even though it does not meet it).

Answer (score 1):

This sort of scenario would be best solved by using [WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54xbah2z.aspx) or [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) as the host for your rendering system. I have worked with such systems before and I found using [SlimDX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) with [WPF Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx) was my preferred solution. Using this approach allows for the addition of nice UI features provided by WPF, overlain on a 3D model rendered to a surface.